# CodeIgniter URL, File, Controller organization. What is the best way?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new at CodeIgniter framework with also MVC, thus i have confused how the organization should be.

I will write a large application. I need well organized File Structure.

For example, i have categories with also products, records etc.. which are unique to a category. I have a admin panel.

Here is my URL for controlling categories at admin panel:

Index(List of categories): mysite.com/index.php/admin/category/index
Create(Creating new category): mysite.com/index.php/admin/category/create

First of all i need a dashboard for categories which shows their products, records etc..
I want the new url to be like:

```
mysite.com/index.php/admin/category/id/5
or
mysite.com/index.php/admin/category/name/category1
etc..
```

I want products url to be like:

```
mysite.com/index.php/admin/category/id/5/product
and records to be like:
mysite.com/index.php/admin/category/id/5/record
```

Of course i need to parse value's to products or records like:

```
mysite.com/index.php/admin/category/id/5/product/id/5
or
mysite.com/index.php/admin/category/id/5/product/create - to add new product to a category
```

As i said before my application is large
I thought file organization something like this:

```
controllers/admin.php - admin controller
controllers/admin/category.php - category controller
controllers/admin/category/product.php - product controller
controllers/admin/category/record.php - record controller
```

I need your advices how to make organization.
How can i show products unique to a category

Should My product controller extends from category controller etc.. Can you help and advice me please? Thanks.

Comment: for a huge project I recommand you Symfony2 framework with its "bundle" architecture. It will give you less freedom in file architecture, so people who know how symfony2 works will also know how is structured your project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to answer your question which is understand by me.

First of all CodeIgnitor with easy file structure.

```
Basic : 
   application/
              Controller/ put all controller 
              model/ put all model 
              views/ put view file 

 // In your case:

         controllers/admin.php - admin controller
         controllers/category.php - category controller
         controllers/product.php - product controller
         controllers/record.php - record controller
```

you have little mis-interpolation:

```
   mysite.com/index.php/admin/category/id/5/product/id/5

   GET method
   //serverpath(base_url)/controller/method(function)/para1/valu1/para2/valu2....
```

In your case category and product is conttroller.

please refer CI-codeIgnitor documents: 
      http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

Hope you understand.